# References for Bloch space

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, banach-spaces

I'm studing the Bloch space $\mathcal{B}$, but I don't find many references for this topic, I only find some papers. Could you give me some references that contain this topic in depth, such as basic properties, some examples, etc ?

Thank you very much

Comment: not clear what you're asking with how it's related to "the" Banach space. Of course the Bloch space _is_ a Bsnach space

Comment: I would look in the book Geometric Function Theory in One and Higher dimensions by I Graham and G Kohr and start from chapter 1.4 there and references inside; https://www.taylorfrancis.com/books/mono/10.1201/9780203911624/geometric-function-theory-one-higher-dimensions-ian-graham-gabriela-kohr